# Can a data science postdoc improve their chances in industry as a pure science graduate?

Tags: postdocs, industry, data-science

Long story short, I defended my PhD in pure mathematics in a top-tier university in Europe but decided I'm saturated with the toxic mentality of the group so I wanted to look for a position in the industry. Although my thesis was on pure probability, I taught classes in machine learning and have some knowledge of the domain so I thought that I might be a good fit for a junior position in data science.

I interviewed at a [FAANG](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/FAANG) company, but then the hiring freeze happened. As my home country is known for its high-tech industry (but not the quality of universities) I tried to search there. 6 months later and after sending my CV over 350 times through LinkedIn I am totally anxious, exhausted and feel either the market is hard or I'm not a completely competent candidate.

A few days ago I saw an announcement on LinkedIn for a postdoc and I was so tired that I clicked the button. Seemingly the guy is from the computational neuroscience group of a university here and he asked if I am interested collaborating (probably for a postdoc) for a data science job.

On the one hand it's a job, probably at minimum wage. On the other hand I am too traumatized by academia even now, I don't want to get close to it ever again and have strong doubts that a data-scientific postdoc counts towards experience I need.

Can you share from your experience if a postdoc in data science helps people to find a job in industry afterwards?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I know Python

Comment: There are jobs on fraud-detection using "data science" (whatever that means). I know people who might be hiring

Answer (score 13):

Have you thought about the opposite problem? You might be overqualified? You hold a PhD in mathematics and you apply for junior positions. At the moment companies struggle to find people with data science and AI background. At our university students don't even finish the bachelor because they get too good offers from industry while still being students.

Another explanation: your CV sounds too academic and HR departments don't even understand your qualifications. Remove academic details that don't matter outside of academia and write a simple-to-understand CV (max 1 page).